# Is it legal to call a React hook function inside an event handler function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I came across this code example from [FullstackOpen](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/a_more_complex_state_debugging_react_apps#a-function-that-returns-a-function):

```js
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10)

  const setToValue = (newValue) => {
    console.log('value now', newValue)
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {value}
      <button onClick={() => setToValue(1000)}>
        thousand
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setToValue(0)}>
        reset
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setToValue(value + 1)}>
        increment
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You can see that `setValue(newValue)` is called inside `setToValue` which is a arrow function. Now, is this best practice? Because I thought *a hook* should be called from top level of functional component, but here it is called inside an arrow function that resides inside a functional component?

I guess I'm asking why is it OK to call a hook inside an event handler function? Thanks.

Comment: `I thought a hook should be called from top level of functional component` That's true, but the only hook in this code is `useState`. `setValue` is not a hook, it's just being *returned* by a hook. Feel free to call `setValue` in an `onClick` callback.